# Store username in array from login to server

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, go

I have a small Go web-server that displays data to users as they login. The problem I'm trying to achieve is to have the web-page only show certain information when a specific user logs in. For example, when admin logs in there would be a list of admin-only items that they can see on the web-page.

The problem I'm having is for some reason my Go code isn't storing the username in the array that I'm calling, so when I pass it over to the JavaScript it is blank.

Here are the 3 main parts of the code that I'm struggling with:

`main.go`

```
package main

import "fmt"

func authHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    usernameArray, hasUsername := r.PostForm["j_username"]

    //This line added for debugging purposes
    log.Println("username:", usernameArray[0])

    if hasUsername {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", usernameArray[0])
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/getAuth", authHandler)
}
```

---

`javascript.js`

Note that this is AngularJS

```
$scope.init = function() {
    checkAuthentication();
};

checkAuthentication = function() {
    $http.get("/getAuth").then(
    function(response) {
        var username = response.data;

        console.log(username): //Added for debugging purposes

        if (username === "admin") {
            $scope.showAdminOnlyItems = true;
        }
    });
}
```

---

`main.html`

```
<div id="admin-only-items" ng-show="showAdminOnlyItems">
    <hr style="border:1px solid">
    <p style="text-align: center">admin only: </p>
    <div id="adminOnlyButtom">
        <button class="button" data-ng-click="doSomething()">Do something</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Again, I only want that div to show up when admin logs in, and Go needs to send the username over to the javascript to verify that. By adding the debugging line in Go and starting the server up, I get this:

```
2018/11/19 16:28:42 http: panic serving 10.240.49.238:59621: runtime error: 
index out of range
goroutine 26 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc42009f720)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1726 +0xd0
panic(0x79f820, 0xe17940)
        C:/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:502 +0x229
main.authHandler(0xc56220, 0xc420135180, 0xc4207a3500)
        D:/src/main.go:346 +0x1d8
```

So it's clear that the usernameArray is empty, not sure what I did wrong. Can anyone help tell me why the usernameArray is empty in authHandler?

Comment: You should check for `error` value returned from `r.ParseForm()` and use `r.PostFormValue()` instead.

Comment: Also note that r.PostFormValue() would be for a PUT, PATCH, or POST. You're sending an http GET method, which is not expended to send any data.

Comment: How are you sending request data to Go in the first place? The javascript code only send GET request with no data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first, I can see that you send `GET` request to server without `j_username` query param therefore you can not read `j_username` on server side.

The second, `usernameArray` is empty slice which is failing while parse `j_username`. Error `index out of range` occur when you try to call `usernameArray[0]`.

You should send `GET` request with `j_username` like that `/getAuth?j_username=admin` and modify code from server.

```
    usernameArray, hasUsername := r.URL.Query()["j_username"]
    //This line added for debugging purposes
    log.Println("debug here :", usernameArray)

    if hasUsername {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", usernameArray[0])
        return
    }

    // Send an error message to client
    http.Error(w, `missing username`, 500)
```